# How to make QtCreator recognize autocompletion for OpenGL functions when building with CMake?

Tags: qt, opengl, cmake

I am starting to work with Qt+OpenGL for my app. I also noticed that it is possible to use CMake to build the application as [explained here](https://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects)

However, I cannot get Qt to recognize OpenGL functions for the autocompletion. The application builds correctly and runs without problems.

Is there something I must add to the CMake file or a setting in Qt to get the autocompletion?

Here's my CMakeLists.txt if needed

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 2.8 )

PROJECT( QtOpenGLTemplate )

FIND_PACKAGE( Qt5Widgets REQUIRED )
IF( Qt5Widgets_FOUND )
    MESSAGE( STATUS "Qt5 Widgets module FOUND!" )
ELSE()
    MESSAGE( WARNING "Qt5 Widgets module NOT FOUND!" )
ENDIF()

FIND_PACKAGE( Qt5OpenGL REQUIRED )
IF( Qt5OpenGL_FOUND )
    MESSAGE( STATUS "Qt5 OpenGL module FOUND!" )
ELSE()
    MESSAGE( WARNING "Qt5 OpenGL module NOT FOUND!" )
ENDIF()

FIND_PACKAGE( OpenGL REQUIRED )
IF( OPENGL_FOUND )
    MESSAGE( STATUS "OpenGL FOUND!" )
ELSE()
    MESSAGE( WARNING "OpenGL NOT FOUND!" )
ENDIF()

SET( SOURCES main.cpp GLViewer.cpp )

ADD_EXECUTABLE( QtOpenGLTemplate ${SOURCES} )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( QtOpenGLTemplate ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::OpenGL )
```

Comment: from my experience it's something like: `LIST(APPEND INCLUDES OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS)` though I'm not sure

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm testing under OS X, but it is likely that it must work on Ubuntu too.

Comment: It is quite strange because I just tried `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} )` for CUDA and Qt recognizes everything and does autocompletion, so I am missing something for the OpenGL library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in [Qt's CMake manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/cmake-manual.html)

> In order for find_package to be successful, Qt 5 must be found below
>   the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, or the Qt5_DIR must be set in the CMake
>   cache to the location of the Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake file. The easiest
>   way to use CMake is to set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH environment variable
>   to the install prefix of Qt 5.

So by adding the following line to the CMakeLists.txt

```
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} /Applications/Qt/5.3/clang_64")
```

made Qt to recognize and autocomplete OpenGL functions.

Comment: Even if this answers my question, I would like ask if someone knows why setting this variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` works, whereas using `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` does not?